# Error Code: Thread 1:Signal SIGABRT Game timer with NSTimer and NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have been trying to get this to work but I get an Error Code: Thread 1:Signal SIGABRT in the AppDelegate.swift. What I'm trying to do: Create as accurate as possible game timer that will start at a specific date and time. I want to use viewWillLoad(), but I thought to runloop would initialize the NSTimer. I have tried many different ways of approaching this, if there is a better way, please let me know. Would appreciate any help!

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var gameTimerLabel: UILabel!  // Game timer label, should be updated with NSTimer

func updateLabel()-> (String) {

    let startDateAsString = "Mon, 12 Apr 2016 12:00:00 MDT"  // Start date as a string
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"

    let startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(startDateAsString) // Start date as NSDate

    let now = NSDate()
    let difference = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate!) // Time since start date


    let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()  // Format so time is in Min:Sec
    let timer = dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(difference)
    self.gameTimerLabel.text = timer!   // Updating Label
    return timer!                   // Tried to use the return value to update timer

}
   // Timer set up, should fire updateLabel each time
func timerSetup(){
let myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: "updateLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact crash log you are getting ? From where you are calling the timerSetup method ? What is the purpose of returning that String from updateLabel function ?

Comment: Have you tried to add an exception breakpoint to get more info about crash reason?

Comment: @MidhunMP I get the crash log in another file, the default AppDelegate.swift, i've made no changes to it. I need to call the timerSetup, you are correct, when I call it I get the error code "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call. I was returning the String as the timer to update the label, I can remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change

```
func updateLabel()-> (String)
```

to

```
func updateLabel(myTimer:NSTimer)-> (String)
```

Comment: Some description of why it is to be done will be helpful.